# How to trigger this event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two password inputs, each are entered by the password keypad, but no keyboard input. The keypad is a 3 by 3 table with buttons 1 to 9.

**How can I trigger the event when the client mouse cursor leaves the keypad table?**

What I want to do is if the user clicks something and then leaves the keypad, validate and confirm password input.

I tried to add `onmouseout` and div wrapper to the table, but it was not what I expected because when the cursor hovers over the button, the event fires.

```
<table onmouseout="ValidatorEnable()">
```

Comment: Can you post a small HTML sample that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some work on this. First of all on ready event of document get size and position of table or div containing keypad. then in mouseout event on that container check if current cursor is out of the boundaries of container.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tp=0;//top
    var lft=0;//left
    var rht=0;//right
    var bot=0;//bottom
    function CheckBounds(x,y){
       return (x < tp || y < lft) || (x > rht || y > bot);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       tp=$("#tbl").position().top;
       lft=$("#tbl").position().left;
       rht=$("#tbl").width() + lft;
       bot=$("#tbl").height() + tp;

       $("#tbl").mouseout(function(e){
          if(CheckBounds(e.pageX, e.pageY)){
             //DO Validation here
          }
       });
    }):
</script>
```

PS:- I've tested it in FF 3.5 with firebug. Chrome crashed!

Answer (score 0):

As usually, developers don't validate input when onmouseout of table, but onblur of input or you can fire ValidatorEnable() when you click the button.Best wishes!

Comment: normal is onblur, but it is for the field only input by keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is probably to make a "background" div appear as big as the viewport with a lower z-index than your keypad, but higher than anything else, and set the onMouseOver event of that "background" cover to do your validation. Coincidentally, you can use an onclick event on it to also close the keypad and validate.